# Pushing onto an STL stack is pass by reference, but does the stack make a copy of the value?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

Checking the documentation online I saw that it is pass by reference.  Can someone confirm that the stack actually makes a copy of the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [it does copy the element you give it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/push). In C++11, it can also move it if you give it a temporary or `std::move` into it.

Note that C++11 also offers [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/emplace), which directly constructs the value in-place, given constructor arguments.

Comment: @NiklasB.: You were 30 seconds faster than me ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The value is copied but it might not work as you thought. If you are pushing a pointer, such as `char*`, it'll copy just the pointer value, and not the entire string. If you are pushing a simple `int`, or `CustomObject` but not the pointer, it'll be copied.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to the `stack` adapter itself is by reference, but remember that `stack` is just an adapter -- its `push` immediately calls the `push_back`, passing that same parameter. This call, however, passes the parameter by value.

Therefore, the parameter you pass does get copied -- the pass by reference to `std::stack` means that it only gets copied once. If that was a pass by value, then it would be copied twice (ignoring, for the moment, the compiler eliding the copy, which it almost certainly would).